# How do I get my docusaurus page to start with dark mode as default

Tags: docusaurus

How do I get my docusaurus page to start with dark mode as default instead light mode as it comes by default ? thank you.

Answer (score 8):

In your `docusaurus.config.js`, add/edit the following to

```
module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    colorMode: {
      defaultMode: 'dark',
      disableSwitch: false,
      respectPrefersColorScheme: false,
    },
  },
};
```

Reference: https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration#color-mode---dark-mode